# How to create a django User using DRF's ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In django, creating a User has a different and unique flow from the usual Model instance creation. You need to call `create_user()` which is a method of `BaseUserManager`.

Since django REST framework's flow is to do `restore_object()` and then `save_object()`, it's not possible to simply create Users using a `ModelSerializer` in a generic create API endpoint, without hacking you way through.

What would be a clean way to solve this? or at least get it working using django's built-in piping?

**Edit:**

Important to note that what's specifically not working is that once you try to authenticate the created user instance using `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` it fails if the instance was simply created using `User.objects.create()` and not `.create_user()`.

Comment: Weird... I'm using just `User.objects.create()` and then authenticating the user afterwards. Now I need to figure out why it works.

Comment: Are you also setting the user's password on creation? If not, there's no reason not to use `create()`.

Or if you are setting the password you can call `user.set_password()` separately in restore_object() after the save (the problem here is that you'll be saving the user twice).

Comment: Yes, the password here is the root of all evil. Probably it's being set in its raw form to DB and that's what failing authentication, probably what @alexarsh is suggesting.
What I'll probably go for is moving all the logic form `create_user()` to the `save()` method.

Comment: @YuriPrezument, yes, the password setting was the root of the problem. Now I am setting it using `user.set_password()` in `restore_object()` but that happens before `save()` so you we're  sort of *on it* (:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085996/djangorestframework-registering-a-user-difference-between-userserializer-save/30087194#30087194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I've overridden the serializer's `restore_object` method and made sure that the password being sent is then processes using `instance.set_password(password)`, like so:

```
def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
    if not instance:
        instance = super(RegisterationSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
    instance.set_password(attrs.get('password'))
    return instance
```

Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: I can confirm that this is the right answer when using `Django==1.6.5` and `djangorestframework==2.3.14`. If using `djangorestframework > 3.0` it is likely a different solution involving `post_save()` or `create()` on the ModelSerializer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this is to overwrite `pre_save(self, obj)` method in your extension of `viewsets.GenericViewSet` like so:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    """ We have to encode the password in the user object that will be
    saved before saving it.
    """
    viewsets.GenericViewSet.pre_save(self, obj)
    # Password is raw right now, so set it properly (encoded password will
    # overwrite the raw one then).
    obj.user.set_password(obj.user.password)
```

---

**Edit:**

Note that the obj in the code above contains the instance of User class. If you use Django's user model class directly, replace `obj.user` with `obj` in the code (the last line in 2 places).

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with DRF. And here is how I create users:

I have a Serializer with overrided save method:

```
def save(self, **kwargs ):
    try:
        user = create_new_user(self.init_data)
    except UserDataValidationError as e:
        raise FormValidationFailed(e.form)
    self.object = user.user_profile
    return self.object
```

create_new_user is just my function for user creation and in the view, I just have:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It's not a problem to use a simple API endpoint which calls user.create(**...). The problem is that when trying to authenticate (django's `authenticate()` function) the same user you've just created it simply fails and returns `None`.
Probably cause it's setting the raw password on the instance and not calling `user.set_password(password)`?

Comment: It looks like something you need to handle in your create_new_user function and is not related to DRF.

Comment: Can you look at your DB and check if your user is created? If yes, which fields does it have? Did you set a password to the user?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be overriding `restore_object()` in your serializer, not `save()`. This will allow you to create your object correctly.

However, it looks like you are trying to abuse the framework -- you are trying to make a single `create()` create two objects (the user and the profile). I am no DRF expert, but I suspect this may cause some problems.

You would probably do better by using a custom user model (which would also include the profile in the same object).

Comment: No, I'm not creating a profile, I'm overriding AbstractBaseUser with my own model, so just creating a single instance.
And also, instantiating is not the problem, the problem is that the save instance created by `create()`, and not `create_user()` can't be authenticated with same credentials later on.