# DjangoRestFramework - registering a user: difference between UserSerializer.save() and User.objects.create_user()?

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, user-registration

Suppose I want to register a user (I'm using the User model located in django.contrib.auth.models). Assume this is my serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', )
```

What's the difference between the following views, and which one is recommended when it comes to creating a user?

View A:

```
def createUser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

View B:

```
def createUser(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email = serializer.init_data['email'],
            username = serializer.init_data['username'],
            password = serializer.init_data['password'],
        )

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither of those is perfect. But **View A** looks promising.

- **View A** is a good start, but it is **incomplete** solution. Because `User` creation is **not** simply `User.save`, but rather you have to call `User.create_user` method.
- View B is the correct way to create user by calling `User.create_user`, however, the views contains a **logic** which should actually be **abstracted** within the `Serializer.save()` method.

To solve this, you have to change the behavior of `Serializer.save()` method. Looking at the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances), `Serializer.save()`, will call either `Serializer.create()` or `Serializer.update()`.

In summary, we have to *override* the `Serializer.create()` for user creation and use **View A**.

```
# File: serializers.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email = validated_data['email'],
            username = validated_data['username'],
            password = validated_data['password'],
        )
        return user
```

Comment: Thanks. Why exactly is User creation not just User.save()? Because when I do it, it works (i'm assuming it's not recommended, but how come User.create_user() is the recommended approach, rather than User.save()?).

Comment: Because you do [`normalize_email`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fe914341c83b37fd6aa8fd85620cf49dd2328ab0/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L19-L30) and [`set_password`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fe914341c83b37fd6aa8fd85620cf49dd2328ab0/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L83-L84) when [`create_user`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/72f6513ebaa7a3fd43c26300e9a8c430dc07cdb5/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L140-L147).

Comment: ah, thanks. Answer has been accepted. On a side note, I see that you used "validated_data['username']," but in these two posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078272/django-rest-framework-user-registrations-with-extra-fields and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718091/django-rest-framework-user-registration they used "init_data['username']".  Any reason why init_data wouldn't work in this case?

Comment: @user2719875 I'm not sure, but I think it will still work, but `init_data` is most likely be the raw data (`request.DATA`) which is not validated.