# user registration in django rest framework

Tags: android, python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am creating a server side for android application in DRF which will require user registration and login\logout endpoints. also obviously different permissions when a user logged in.

I followed the rest framework tutorial here - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/ and this example really seeme to cover it all beside the user registration (creation).

In the tutorial they do it from the command line (and they create a superuser). I think the tutorial example is really good for my needs besides not having the registration endpoint.

**My question are:**

- what is the difference between a regular user and a superuser?
- How should I create a registration endpoint for users? I saw this example [DjangoRestFramework - registering a user: difference between UserSerializer.save() and User.objects.create_user()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085996/djangorestframework-registering-a-user-difference-between-userserializer-save) but I am not sure if it will work nicely because in the tutorial they create a superuser.

If it matters, my user model in actually a UserProfile model which includes the user model and added a phone_number...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A regular user has different authorities from superuser and you should customize view for a specific user. Here is [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/) for you to create user in django.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The thing is,  in the link they create a user from the shell, i want to have a url (users/register for example) that will be attached to a view.  In the view I want to create the user (with the user details from the POST request sent to the view)

Comment: and also, what do you mean by "customize view for a specific user"?

Comment: @OfekAgmon It means a regular user will see a different web page from superuser.

Comment: Okay.  But for the first issue -  in the link you posted they show how to create a user from the shell.  I want to create a user in the view so that the user will have a url where he can POST to and register

Comment: @OfekAgmon URL of POST and register for all users should be the same. Right? You just need to create a user and use a common URL to post and register.

Comment: I understand, BUT in the link they show how to create a user from the SHELL command line. I want to create in programmatically (in the view code)..

Comment: @OfekAgmon You can put the code in the CMD line in your view code to create user.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied it from Django documentation as an answer for your first question.

> One of the most powerful parts of Django is the automatic admin
>   interface. Best thing is that you can customise it easily.
>
> If logged in as a superuser, you have access to create, edit, and
>   delete any object (models).
>
> You can create staff user using staff flag. The “staff” flag controls
>   whether the user is allowed to log in to the admin interface (i.e.,
>   whether that user is considered a “staff member” in your
>   organization). Since this same user system can be used to control
>   access to public (i.e., non-admin) sites, this flag differentiates
>   between public users and administrators.
>
> “Normal” admin users – that is, active, non-superuser staff members –
>   are granted admin access through assigned permissions. Each object
>   editable through the admin interface has three permissions: a create
>   permission, an edit permission and a delete permission for all the
>   models you had created.
>
> Django’s admin site uses a permissions system that you can use to give
>   specific users access only to the portions of the interface that they
>   need. When you create a user, that user has no permissions, and it’s
>   up to you to give the user specific permission

You can do something like this for the second question you've asked.

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 from rest_framework.views import APIView
 from rest_framework import status

 class Register(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
      user = User.objects.create(
                username=request.data.get('email'),
                email=request.data.get('email'),
                first_name=request.data.get('firstName'),
                last_name=request.data.get('lastName')
            )
     user.set_password(str(request.data.get('password')))
     user.save()
     return Response({"status":"success","response":"User Successfully Created"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```